# Turn server doesn't give any ice candidates behind NGINX when requested from a firefox browser

Tags: nginx, firefox, udp, webrtc, coturn

I am trying to add NGINX infront of my TURN server, I am using the coturn package.

My NGINX conf looks like this.

```
stream {
     upstream turn
        {
                server 127.0.0.1:5349;
        }
     server {
                listen 443 udp;

                resolver 1.1.1.1;
                proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
                proxy_timeout 15s;
                proxy_protocol on;

                proxy_pass turn;
                ssl_preread on;
     }
}
```

This works on the Chrome browser. I get srflx and relay candidates.

But on Firefox get none of these candidates.

Even on chrome there is a slight difference in the candidates I get with and without NGINX which could be the cause.

Without NGINX:

```
candidate:3646143538 1 udp 1677729535 <my_ip> 59271 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag xmIu network-cost 999

candidate:1499094430 1 udp 33562623 <public_ip_of_my_turn> 63683 typ relay raddr <my_ip> rport 59271 generation 0 ufrag xmIu network-cost 999
```

With NGINX:

```
candidate:4227863252 1 udp 1677729535 127.0.0.1 54974 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag 0nJM network-cost 999

candidate:601945334 1 udp 33562623 <public_ip_of_my_turn> 60590 typ relay raddr 127.0.0.1 rport 54974 generation 0 ufrag 0nJM network-cost 999
```

As we can see i get raddr as localhost. Passing the client IP properly to the backend could solve the issue.

Even in coturn logs:
without NGINX:
`remote <my_ip>:59271`

with NGINX:
`remote 127.0.0.1:54974`

Tried to proxy `$remote_addr` variable. since in the access logs i get the proper ip (my ip).

Answer (score 1):

You're using nginx as a generic TCP proxy. In this configuration, nginx receives external connection from the client and makes a (localhost) TCP connection to the TURN server. This kind of configuration does not allow to preserve user's IP address for the destination.

You would need to use some kind of ip-preserving methods, like using PROXY protocol (which require support from the destination software, I doubt that coturn supports it) or TPROXY configuration.